# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 Encrypted, and my swap acts very very slow... or it`s not working at all...?

Tags: partitioning, gnome, encryption, swap

folks @ 2017, using ubuntu gnome updated, I have the following issue and I am quite sure I am not alone:

I installed Ubuntu Gnome, 17.04, via live USB, and because I do like to be secure, I set up encryption... And, for some reason, moment my laptop starts to use a bit more memory, everything becomes sluggish and VERY unresponsive. Ive set up xkill on the key combination shortcut, but at the moments, when it becomes sluggish, you can`t really EVEN START the xkill... and there is no logic to how much time you wait to unblock. Once, I let it, and it was frozen for 30 minutes, after which, pc continued to work as before did (so the first question would be is there any newer app, which ensures that system is stable and does auto fixes?)

When I check gparted, I do not see my swap space... But I do see it via terminal (as encrypted of course)... and at the shutdown, it says that it cannot turn off / access the swap.

The hard disk is new, and it`s hybrid one (so it is a bit faster, and it should work just fine).

Yes, This is my old laptop, but, still, its quad-core Intel... and I did find proper drivers for my Nvidia card, so it`s not an issue regarding anything else, as far as I can see, but swap space and swapping...

Of course, I used [Zram](http://gionn.net/2012/03/11/zram-on-debian-ubuntu-for-memory-overcommitment/) But it`s still very very sluggish when a lot of memory is used... and at this moment I am thinking at this moment to literally, disable SWAP partition... but because of very bad experiences, when swap doesn't exist, I am quite concerned... and I will wait for now (since this pc is like second, I do not really need it instantly etc).

First Question: How to fix these issues with encrypted swap space, which really knows to be unstable?

Second Is For Ubuntu Team:

Why enable users to encrypt their partitions using installation, and why swap which is encrypted does behave the way it does?

**Real life example, I open chrome, 5 tabs and WhatsApp for ubuntu and whoila, there you go, the mouse becomes literally unresponsive till the end (as well as entire interface and youtube music), and I can kind of hear HDD working ALL THE TIME.**

It`s not a problem if encryption is BETA, but instead of installing it like this, I would really suggest to Ubuntu Gnome Team (at least), to put nearby that checkbox for encryption (during the install), that this IS beta, and that it CAN cause issues / slow pc...

Anyway, I decreased my swappiness, and tried other things as well, with no success regarding the matter...